# can anyone show example of login to gmail and then print first mail to png with phantomjs?

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs

can anyone show example of login to gmail and then print first mail to png with phantomjs?

what i'm trying to understand is an example of login to gmail and then based on result to do another operation on the next web page...

Comment: Any insight into the issues with Gmail? I am able to login to other services using phantomjs, but gmail isn't working (yet the same scripts using chrome instead of phantomjs works). Did you find the issue with gmail specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out [this discussion thread on scripting multi-page interactions](http://groups.google.com/group/phantomjs/browse_thread/thread/db4cfc37caf0213c). It's clearly a little tricky at the moment, since PhantomJS needs to work with asynchronous callbacks, but it seems to be doable, and there's some good code in the discussion.

Comment: i already checked it but had problems specifically with gmail